# Data is not being copied into the temp table in SQL Server while joining with another table un

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select L.* 
into PortTom4L 
from PortTomMsgHist4L L
Inner join PortTomMsgHist P on P.mnmNestOrderNumber = L.mnmNestOrderNumber
where P.DtTime >= convert(datetime, '2020/01/01', 103) 
  and P.DtTime < convert(datetime, '2020/02/01', 103);
```

Comment: Remove "into PortTom4L" to make sure you got data.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: It may you don't have data while you have join, remove "into PortTom4L"  and see the result

Answer (score 0):

Format 103 is DD/MM/YYYY.  Just use a regular date format:

```
select L.* 
into PortTom4L 
from PortTomMsgHist4L L join
     PortTomMsgHist P
     on P.mnmNestOrderNumber = L.mnmNestOrderNumber
where P.DtTime >= '2020-01-01' and
      P.DtTime < '2020-02-01';
```